# Rename massively pdf with bash script using pdftotext (Debian)

Tags: bash, pdf, pdftotext

I am fighting with a simple script to rename several thousand pdf files that contain a numeric string such that '01201900000001' and the truth is that I do not get that far, it would be very much appreciated a help.
Thank you
 My script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PDF_FILE_PATH=$1
echo "Converting pdfs at $PDF_FILE_PATH"
for f in *.pdf; do pdftotext "$f" done
echo $f
NEWNAME=$(sed -n '/N. SINIESTRO/p' "$f")
echo "Renaming pdf $f to $NEWNAME"
mv "f" "PDF_FILE_PATH$NEWNAME"
done


N SINIESTRO is the string that I will extract from each txt to rename its pdf.
 N SINIESTRO = 01201900000003
```

Comment: Copy and paste your script to https://shellcheck.net And also note that your shebang says `/bin/sh`, that means this is a `sh` script, not `bash`, they're not exactly the same, `bash` is an implemention of `sh` with fancy extensions which other implementions might not support

Comment: Also note there are differences in pdf file contents. If the pdf file contains a bitmap of text, pdftotext will be meaningless.The only way to get text from the file in that case is OCR.

Comment: Read about code indentation.  With that simple technique, you would have noticed some syntax errors.  An editor with syntax highlighting and code folding will also help.  shellcheck.net, as suggested above, is perfect.  Ex. 2 `done`, missing $ in front of the PDF_FILE_PATH, ...

Comment: It will help if you can clarify the question - provide the rename rule, and few examples.